# MongoDB copyDatabase() failure

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to make a copy of a fairly large Mongo database.(about 410GB) using the mongo command db.copyDatabase(). I log in as Admin and issue the command

```
 result = db.copyDatabase("warehouse","tswcopy2")
```

The copy starts and runs for around an hour at which point it terminates with

`error code 121 "Document failed validation"`.

Does anyone have insight? Is it possible that document validation on one of my collections is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Document failed validation - Occurs when there is a validation error in the document.

This will occur when `db.collection.insert / db.collection.update` - violates the validator rule which we mentioned while creating the collection. More Info on Document Validation

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/document-validation/

https://jaihirsch.github.io/straw-in-a-haystack/mongodb/2015/12/04/mongodb-document-validation/

Please check the following to narrow down the issue/fix the issue

- Get Collection Info on source DB and Target DB https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionInfos/
- Run full collection validate on source DB https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.validate/

If full collection validate is successful, then check for the collectionInfo on source and target DB, if there is any validator mismatch between these two DB's.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After turning validation off the error went away. Personally I think validation should not be applied when creating a copy. If I request a copy, that is what I want, warts and all.

Answer (score 0):

After removing validation from my collections this fault went away. What this makes clear is that the db.copyDatabase() command is not doing a low level copy. All documents that are moved from the existing database to the new database are subject to document validation. This is problematic if you have changed the document structure since the creation of the database and and now strictly enforce the shape of a documents.

I would argue that, when copying a database, validation should should be turned off as you are requesting a copy of a database not a validated copy. At the very least validation should be optional.

**EDIT:**

I logged a fault with MongoDB and, amazingly I got a response almost immediately which can be seen here [https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27059](http://MongoDB-JIRA-Issue)

It turns out there is an undocumented feature!

```
db.adminCommand({copydb: 1, 
                 fromdb: dbName, 
                 todb: copyDbName, 
                 bypassDocumentValidation: true});
```

Full marks to MongoDB for thier response time.

Comment: What do you mean "undocumented"?  It's been documented from the start: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2/#document-validation

Comment: Not according to your own help desk it wasnt (see the above jira log). As I said the help desk response time was very quick though!

Comment: I think you are confusing an undocumented option on a command with an undocumented *feature*.

Comment: Slightly pedantic don't you think?